# How to better store user auth data and their detailed information separated

Tags: mongodb, authentication, database

I want to keep user account separated from infos about them, e.g. "account data" - login, password, email... and "detailed info" - name, age...

For it I want to have two different tables. Is it good way to implement user handling? I see it as a safe way to keep executing operations on users and not to accidentally harm their authentication data. So, if it is an okay way, than how can I connect these two tables, so I could login on site and after that manipulate  this user data without querying auth table? What is the better way to store users?

Comment: If you're afraid of accidentally modifying things, how exactly would separating things into two tables help? You should fix your accidental modification issue instead.

Comment: @deceze seprarting would help in case if for example was removed, but user would still be able to login with his credentials, but with lost personal information.

Comment: Why are login information by themselves less likely to be removed than if they were combined with other information…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very broad question. Its better to keep your tables normalized.

Database Normalisation is a technique of organizing the data in the database. Normalization is a systematic approach of decomposing tables to eliminate data redundancy and undesirable characteristics like Insertion, Update and Deletion Anamolies.

In your case, if authentication & profile update are 2 seprate operations, so better keep the tables separate.

P.S. Being programmer, you should not accidentally update the tables :)